# Dynamically import an arbitrary JS module in react app built with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

*I've looked at the similar issues and documentation for dynamically importing modules, but they don't seem to work (I think they are designed to import part of an existing project).*

I'm trying to dynamically import modules which are not known at compile time. Essentially, I get a string which is the URL path to a JS module, and then import it. In theory, this should be possible with the `import()` function, but within a react app this seems to fail to find the module.

When loading the page, the react code errors with `Error: Cannot find module '/js'`. But, in the console on the same page, I can run this without a problem: `import("/js").then((mod) => console.log(mod))`

This suggests to me that react is using a custom `import()` function, rather than the browser supplied one. Is there a way to bypass and use the browser's version, or some other way to get this to work dynamically with an arbitrary URL?

I am using `react-scripts build` to build my app with webpack.

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Built using yarn (which calls `react-scripts build`).

Comment: Use this to add `webpackIgnore` at build time: https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments#webpackignore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `react-scripts` you are using webpack to build your app. To prevent webpack from parsing your dynamic `import()` statements you can use an ignore [magic comment](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) to disable webpack's parsing and default to the browser's native implementation.

An example of using the `webpackIgnore` magic comment to bypass webpack's parsing:

```js
import(/* webpackIgnore: true */ '/js')
```

If you wanted to add these magic comments to all of your dynamic imports at build time, you can use [`magic-comments-loader`](https://github.com/morganney/magic-comments-loader) and add this rule to your webpack configuration:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'magic-comments-loader',
        options: {
          webpackIgnore: true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course, you would need to eject your build or use something like [`craco`](https://craco.js.org/).

Comment: The magic comment was the missing piece for me. Thank you!